# Old themes in the Design configuration page of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, theme-fallback

I've deleted all **TemplateMonster** theme files and it's still showing in the Design configuration page.

Process completed to remove themes:

1. Remove theme files from **app/design/frontend**
2. Clear static file cache
3. Remove from **var/**

There's also Testing Custom Theme that shows two instances for reason, but in **app/design/frontend** there's only one. (I've cleared static file cache)

Any experience with this strange behavior, folks?
[image]

Comment: want to remove those entry from admin?

Comment: Already tried it.
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php on line 751`

Comment: its working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now in your case, you have to just remove entry from database table **theme**.

Go to Database,
find Table name **`theme`** and find entry with your theme name.
Remove entry from table and you can check now in admin.
Now you cant see those old theme in your configuration.

try with above tricks and plz let me know if any issue,
Thanks.